# Moving issues from excel to github organization

Tags: github, github-api, organization, github-organizations

I am trying to move a bunch of issues from excel to GitHub issues.

The problem I am encountering is that I can not figure out how to use get an access token for an organization in order to automate pushing the issues to GitHub.

I tried to make an OAuth token for that organization but I keep getting an bad credential error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your [OAuth token has a "repo" scopr](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/#available-scopes).

Then try [creating a new issue](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue) (as [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/RickCogley/14e5a4c2ffec1d06606a554cdd5033d9))

```
curl -X "POST" "https://api.github.com/repos/rickcogley/REPONAME/issues?state=all" \
     -H "Cookie: logged_in=no" \
     -H "Authorization: token THEd13GITHUBfb87TOKENa4FROM5eSETTINGS" \
     -H "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" \
     -d $'{
  "title": "A workflow alerts Operator who performs a process",
  "body": "TBD",
  "milestone": 5,
  "assignees": [
    "RickCogley",
    "NathanielPhillips"
  ],
  "labels": [
    "story",
    "#2",
    "enhancement",
    "production"
  ]
}'
```

Comment: Is the OAuth token you are referring to the same as a personal token or is that the secret id for a OAuth app?

Comment: @avan989 OAuth App: https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/creating-an-oauth-app/